# How to "update" an immutable element in an immutable set in Scala?

Tags: scala, set, immutability

I have a `Set` of elements that have their equality defined around a key, but other fields can be different... So when I need to 'update', this is what I've tried:

```
object sandbox {

  case class K(val id: Int, val message: String) {
    override def equals(that: Any) = that match {
      case K(this.id, _) => true
      case _ => false
    }
    override def hashCode = this.id
    override def toString = "(" + id + "," + message + ")"
  }

  val s = Set(K(1, "a"), K(2, "b"))               //> s  : scala.collection.immutable.Set[test.sandbox.K] = Set((1,a), (2,b))
  val updatedElem = K(1, "c")                     //> updatedElem  : test.sandbox.K = (1,c)

  s + updatedElem                                 //> res0: scala.collection.immutable.Set[test.sandbox.K] = Set((1,a), (2,b))

  Set(updatedElem) | s                            //> res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[test.sandbox.K] = Set((1,c), (2,b))
  }
```

Adding an element that is already there won't change the set, and removing it first and adding the updated again seems kind of sub-optimal.

The `union` method preserves the elements of the set on the left side, but that behaviour is not documented; so I shouldn't rely on it.

So now, is there something more obvious that I am missing? Should I rely on the actual behaviour (and write a test just in case it changes)? Or should I do the update in two steps?

Comment: The set is using a hash code that relies on the `id` only. This would mean that `K(1, "a") == K(1, "c")` and would explain set not adding(without an exception being throws). Try a hash that factors the different messages.

Comment: then I'd get two objects rather than the previous one replaced

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my point of view, it is actually a problem of concepts in modelling. The point is that equal objects should really be equivalent... otherwise you may want to consider some other structures. For example, why not try `Map` that maps `id` to `message` (or `id` to `K(id,message)`)? That seems much more cleaner in concepts, and then you can use `.updated(1,"c")` to update it.

Comment: Quite true, that was another option that I was considering; but most of the time I think I'll need to access the whole structure including the key (there are some fields more), so I thought that the set would be more convenient.

Comment: @fortran Could you show a use case of the set you build? I think it is clear how you create and modify the set, but I cannot see how you use it. If you can provide that info in the question, maybe people can help more.

Comment: I don't have one yet, it's just a feeling ^_^ It is for a game, it's the `Player` structure that holds current score, the tokens in the hand, etc.

Comment: @fortran you can always put the whole `K` object in the map. You can even define a subclass of `Map` with an additional method to directly add the element without specifying the key `def +(k: K) = +(k.id -> k)`